# AngularJS request with form

Tags: angularjs, forms, request, angular-ui-router

I was looking here in the site and I couldn't find anything that would help me.
I have to send parameters to one route, and I have to use form, how do I send the parameters.
the HTML code:

```
<form ui-sref="root.logiguala" method="get">
  Campo:
  <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="field">
  Valor:
  <input type="text" name="values" ng-model="values">

  <button type="submit">Carregar</button>
</form>
```

And this is supposed to comunicate with:

```
{
    name: 'root.logiguala',
    url: '/LogIgualA/:field/:values',
    params: {
      field: { value: null },
      values: { value: null } 
    },    
    views: {
      main: 'home',
    },resolve: {
      logs: function(pageService,$stateParams) {
        return pageService.LogIgualA($stateParams.field,$stateParams.values);

    }
  },
},
```

(I really don't know the correct terminology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui.router` accepts parameters for your states. You probably want to write it as:

```
<button ui-sref="root.logiguala({'field': field, 'values': values})">Carregar</button>
```

---

Or, if you want to use form submission:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
```

and (*in controller*)

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  $state.go('root.logiguala', {'field': $scope.field, 'values': $scope.values});
}
```

(don't forget to inject `$state` into your controller)

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is passing data between routes, use a factory instead with a set and get method. On first route set the value in the factory, go to the target route and then get the value from factory.

Comment: And how should I do that? (Yes im a totally beginner with AngularJS)